ShowdownJS: Setting flavor to 'github' doesn't affect Markdown to HTML conversion
I am trying to use showdownjs to convert markdown to html format. I want the converted markdown to look as beautiful as default github markdown e.g. showdownjs's README. Here is the code so far.
    ....
    var converter = new showdown.Converter({ 
        simplifiedAutoLink: true,
        tables: true,
        tasklists: true,
        simpleLineBreaks: true,
        openLinksInNewWindow: true
    });
converter.setFlavor('github');

    var htmlContent = converter.makeHtml(markdownContent);

    document.getElementById('markdown-content').innerHTML = htmlContent;
    ....

I have added setFlavor('github') according to markdownjs documentation. However, I see no difference no matter which flavor I use e.g. vanilla, github. Any idea why this might be happening?
Here is entire code for reference and easy reproducibility.
